# EF Core DateTime being assigned on update

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Hi I have a MySQL database connected to my application using EF Core I have just found a bug I'd like to get fixed. I can see that my CreatedDateTime column is set to update to the current timestamp on UPDATE which I don't want as if the user is updating a comment the CreatedDateTime should remain the same but its updated to the current DateTime therefor loosing its original data.

So far I have tried

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
```

and also tried on my configuration entity

```
public class CommentEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Comment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comment> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedDateTime).ValueGeneratedNever();
    }
}
```

And I have tried setting the CreatedDateTime to itself on my update method but it seems like the current timestamp is being set after automatically.

But this isn't having any effect as its still set to update the date & time on every update call, I could just edit the database manually but I'd like to sort it out within EF Core if I can.

The code for my Comment model

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DeletedDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public void Delete()
    {
        if (IsDeleted)
        {
            return;
        }

        IsDeleted = true;
        DeletedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }

    public void Restore()
    {
        IsDeleted = false;
        DeletedDateTime = null;
    }

    public void Update(string commentText, DateTimeOffset createdDateTime)
    {
        CommentText = commentText;
        CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
    }

    public Comment()
    {

    }

    public Comment(string comment, int createdById)
    {
        CommentText = comment;
        CreatedById = createdById;
        CreatedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        IsDeleted = false;
    }
}

public class CommentEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Comment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comment> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedDateTime).ValueGeneratedNever();
    }
}
```

[image: Database schema]

Thank you any help is much appreciated, as I'd love to get this bug sorted.

Comment: Did you check the database?  This default date maybe there , not in EF

Comment: Hi yeah the database is generated by EF core it seems to be setting ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP by default, it hasn't done it on DeletedDateTime maybe because its nullable, I guess some workarounds is make CreatedDateTime nullable but it wouldn't make sense as there should always be a value there. Or I guess I could manually edit the table but it would be nice to specially say not to make it update the date time on every update call in the model builder.

Comment: Can you show us the model definition of you table? And have actually tried changing the column definition on the database itself? Clearly, if you remove it there, it will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special attributes. Just make CreatedDateTime nullable:

```
 public DateTimeOffset? CreatedDateTime
```

and check your database. Fix the column  too if it is needed.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I just ended up doing that in the end which is a workaround for now :) .